# How to find the last valid index in list except the NaN

Tags: python, indexing, nan

My final goal is to find the valid lists satisfying some condition.
I have several lits that have several float and np.nan value.
I like to select the lists that don't have nan value in some range.

Here is one of the lists that I have.

```
list = 
[          nan  -38.10940798  -52.15497422  -68.94011301 -112.58576732
 -110.27810095 -110.61354039 -131.82121921 -137.27076671 -134.34755197
 -125.4644195  -128.78669345 -134.30116567 -136.47002098 -142.14361377
 -142.86356029 -136.64266941 -128.34936325 -121.94468169 -131.72934853
 -135.34244008 -134.77085591 -137.3350188  -139.08824299 -140.45602586
 -143.47342506 -142.41400071 -139.16437999 -139.41824163 -141.88900778
 -142.26951505 -142.5739776  -142.6418401  -144.03415115 -142.03099862
 -141.96427292 -139.52750524 -137.56815712           nan           nan
           nan           nan           nan           nan           nan
           nan           nan           nan           nan           nan
           nan           nan           nan           nan           nan
           nan           nan           nan           nan           nan
           nan           nan           nan           nan           nan]
```

So, I like to filter out this list because this list has nan from index -25 to index -1

I tried

```
if np.nansum(list[-25:-1]) == 0
    list = np.nan
```

I tried

```
if np.nanmean(list[-25:-1]) == 0
    list = np.nan
```

didn't work both cases.

I have several lists that do not have nan and have nan.
So, just what I want to do is 
1) select list that has nan from exact range
2) and make that list having all nan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you're using NumPy, so here's one approach:

```
s = '''          nan  -38.10940798  -52.15497422  -68.94011301 -112.58576732
 -110.27810095 -110.61354039 -131.82121921 -137.27076671 -134.34755197
 -125.4644195  -128.78669345 -134.30116567 -136.47002098 -142.14361377
 -142.86356029 -136.64266941 -128.34936325 -121.94468169 -131.72934853
 -135.34244008 -134.77085591 -137.3350188  -139.08824299 -140.45602586
 -143.47342506 -142.41400071 -139.16437999 -139.41824163 -141.88900778
 -142.26951505 -142.5739776  -142.6418401  -144.03415115 -142.03099862
 -141.96427292 -139.52750524 -137.56815712           nan           nan
           nan           nan           nan           nan           nan
           nan           nan           nan           nan           nan
           nan           nan           nan           nan           nan
           nan           nan           nan           nan           nan
           nan           nan           nan           nan           nan'''

a = np.fromstring(s, sep=' ')
if np.isnan(a[-25:-1]).all(): # check if all values in range are NaN
    a[:] = np.nan             # Set all values to NaN
```

---

To find the last valid index you could do:

```
len(a) - (~np.isnan(a))[::-1].argmax()
# 38
```

Comment: what is the difference between: a = np.nan vs a[:] = np.nan

Comment: a[:] = np.nan is modifying in place. So not creating a copy @DonggyunKim

Comment: One more question... I would like to find the last valid index. In that case, the valid index should be 32. How can I find the index? (Just right before the nan)

Comment: I think it should be 38 @DonggyunKim